# PHP7 + OpenSSL-1.0.2h on CentOS 7 [Nginx 1.11.1]

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, openssl, centos7, php7

Since yesterday, I've applied OpenSSL-1.0.2h to my Nginx server, which I both recompiled from source. For the OpenSSL part, I've followed this guide: https://syslint.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-openssl-on-centos-7-or-rhel-7/. It was relatively easy compiling Nginx afterwards with:

```
./configure --prefix=/etc/nginx ... --with-openssl=/usr/local/src/openssl-1.0.2h
```

## Background information

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016

$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl

$ ls /usr/bin/openssl
/usr/bin/openssl -> /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl

$ find / -name "openssl"
...
/usr/include/openssl
/usr/local/src/openssl-1.0.2h/apps/openssl
/usr/local/src/openssl-1.0.2h/include/openssl
/usr/local/src/openssl-1.0.2h/.openssl/include/openssl
/usr/local/src/openssl-1.0.2h/.openssl/bin/openssl
/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl
/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl
...

$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.11.1
built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016

$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

$ php -i
...
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
Native OpenSSL support => enabled
...
```

Unfortunately, Googling' around and searching the PHP docs (http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php) didn't help for me. I thought about recompiling PHP with the newest OpenSSL by supplying:

```
./configure -disable-shared ... --with-openssl=/usr/local/src/openssl-1.0.2h
```

however this tells me:

```
configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's libraries
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install openssl-devel(`yum install openssl-devel`). Then you could recompile PHP with latest OpenSSL.

Comment: `yum info openssl-devel` gives me `Version     : 1.0.1e`